# Opennign the On-Screen Keyboard on TextBox Focus

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am working on a WPF application which is installed on a tablet PC which runs Windows 7.

I want to open the On-Screen keyboard every time a TextBox get focused.

**The On-Screen keyboard's process is running all the time, and if the user wants to use the keyboard he need to slide his fingers throw the top left corner of the screen.**

How do I force the keyboard to be opened when the textbox get focused?

Comment: I believe this is the default behavior of the built-in OSK *so long as a physical keyboard is not attached*.  Do you want to bring up the OSK even when a physical keyboard is plugged in?

Comment: A physical keyboard is not plugged, The keyboard is hidden all time, so I want the OSK to popup when a textbox get focused.

Answer (score 1):

You could start a new OSK process within textbox focused event,

```
Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

Comment: The process is already running.. The keyboard is just hidden, so my purpose is to get the keyboard shown when I want.

Comment: That code will start the process if it isn't running.  If it *is* running, it will simply open the window of the already-running process.  The end result should be exactly what you're after.

Comment: Not working... The keyboard is still not shown when calling `Process.Start("osk.exe");`